# How to add several layout in Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, laravel, layout, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a new layout in my Laravel project following x-app-layout but I receive an error:
Unable to locate a class or view for component [driven-layout].

I've create in resources/views/layout dir my driven.blade.php.

But my blade page can't locate my new layout.

What I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To referance `x-driven-layout` the same way as `x-app-layout` is used, you will need to create a file in `app/View/Components/DrivenLayout.php` in addition to your existing blade file.

```php
// app/View/Components/DrivenLayout.php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class DrivenLayout extends Component
{
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represents the component.
     */
    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('layouts.driven');
    }
}
```